# What is meaning of "let $\mathcal E$ be a m.a.d.f.extending $\mathcal E_0$"?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

What is meaning of "let $\mathcal E$ be a m.a.d.f.extending $\mathcal E_0$"? Does such $\mathcal E$ always exist?

Thanks ahead:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending a family to a MAD family is trivial using Zorn's lemma. Consider all the AD families extending $\cal E_0$ and order them by inclusion. It is easy to verify that every chain has an upper bound, so there is a maximal element.

A Maximal AD family is precisely a MAD family, and obviously it extends $\cal E_0$.